# Having trouble patching MongoDB document with Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am working on a Node.js application with Mongoose and TypeScript that interacts with a MongoDB database. I'm trying to implement a patch endpoint that allows me to update an existing document in my MongoDB database. However, my patch endpoint doesn't seem to be working as expected, and I'm getting an HTTP error 500.

Here's the patch endpoint in my backend:

```
//Product Patch
router.patch("/:productId", (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    const updateOps = {};
    for (const ops of req.body) {
      updateOps[ops.propName] = ops.value;
      console.log(ps.propName);
    }
    product.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: updateOps })
      .exec()
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).json(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
  });
```

And here's the **`product`** model class in my backend:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ArtikelNr: String,
  produktName: String,
  produktBeschreibung: String,
  lagerbestand: String,
  imagestring: String,
  preis: Number,
  isFavorit: Boolean,
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

In my frontend, I have a **`product`** class that I'm using as the **`updateObject`**:

```
import { Types } from 'mongoose'; // Import Types from mongoose

export class product {
    produktName: string;
    produktBeschreibung: string;
    lagerbestand: number;
    imagestring: string;
    ArtikelNr: string;
    preis:  number;
    isFavorit:  boolean = true;
    _id!: Types.ObjectId;

    constructor(produktName: string, produktBeschreibung: string, lagerbestand: number, imageData: string, ArtikelNr: string, preis: number, isFavorit: boolean) {
        this.produktName = produktName;
        this.produktBeschreibung = produktBeschreibung;
        this.lagerbestand = lagerbestand;
        this.imagestring = imageData;
        this.ArtikelNr = ArtikelNr;
        this.preis = preis;
        this.isFavorit = isFavorit;
    }
}
```

When I try to make a patch request with the following function in my frontend:

```
PatchProd(productParam: product) {
    const productId = productParam._id;
    var updateObject: product = new product(productParam.produktName, productParam.produktBeschreibung, productParam.lagerbestand, productParam.imagestring, productParam.ArtikelNr, productParam.preis, productParam.isFavorit);
    console.log('Changes are being saved...');
    console.log('Product Object:', updateObject); // Verify if the product object is correct
    // HTTP request
    this.http.patch(`MyURL/${productId}`, updateObject)
      .subscribe({
        next: res => {
          console.log('HTTP request successful:', res);
        },
        error: error => {
          console.log('Error in HTTP request:', error);
        }
      });
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: _HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: 'OK', url: MyURL/CorrectDocumentId', ok: false, …
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?